# How can I do multi CMD in docker?

Tags: docker

I want to do this 2 command.

```
CMD ["supervisord", "-n",]
CMD ["busybox" , "crond", "-b", "-L", "/dev/stderr"]
```

I know work only last CMD. So I tried these command one by one.But it doesn't work.

```
CMD ["supervisord", "-n", "&&" , "busybox" , "crond", "-b", "-L", "/dev/stderr"]

CMD ["supervisord", "-n", ";" , "busybox" , "crond", "-b", "-L", "/dev/stderr"]

CMD supervisord -n; busybox crond -b -L /dev/stderr
```

If you know how to solve this problem please tell me!

Comment: Add a shell script to the docker that has all the commands you want to run and then run that script with the CMD in the dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a shell script, for bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# file: startup.sh
supervisord -n
busybox crond -b -L /dev/stderr
```

then in dockerfile do:

```
...
COPY startup.sh /startup.sh
RUN chmod 744 /startup.sh
...
CMD ["/startup.sh"]
```

Comment: RUN chmod 744 /startup.sh  is also need before CMD

Answer (score 1):

Can you run both commands on the same line?

`CMD supervisord -n && busybox crond -b -L /dev/stderr`